# Unable to use playn JSON classes in Eclipse

Tags: playn

I'm not able to access the playn.core.json.* classes inside eclipse even though everything else works in general. I have used this http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted in setting up my eclipse project.
However the following classes are visible -

JsonImpl
JsonParserException
JsonSink
JsonTypedArray
JsonWriterException

When I go to the referenced libraries in Eclipse, I can see playn.core.json and 
can see all classes inside it. I'm just not able to use them inside my 
code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw the samples.

You're supposed to use the interface Json.Object/Json.Array.
Use PlayN.json().createObject() to create a new Json.Object instance, and PlayN.json().createArray() to create a new Json.Array instance.

Make sure you have statically imported playn.core.PlayN.*